# Botframework (V4-preview) updated conversation state values not persisted across conversations

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using MS Botframework V4(preview) testing via emulator. I'm using conversation-state to maintain few configurations.In `startup.cs` I have declared the state as(for local testing)

```
  options.Middleware.Add(new ConversationState<Dictionary<string, object>>(new MemoryStorage()));
```

When a user interacts with my chatbot,say for example in 4th coversation step i'm updating the state values as below

```
var state = context.GetConversationState<Dictionary<string, object>>();
state["IsActiveDialog"] = false;
state.Remove("CurrentActiveDialog");
```

In the following conversation step(say step 5), if I examine the state ,my changes to the state were not affected. i.e still `state["IsActiveDialog"]` showing `true` and `CurrentActiveDialog` property has not been removed

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Please share the implementation/code snippet of your WaterfallSteps so that we can reproduce and troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

V4 is preview and is undergoing active development, so there is a lot of turnover. If you'd like to implement this in the current revision for the C# SDK in V4 there's a sample that demonstrates this:

[AspNetCore-EchoBot-AppInsights](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/e58e997a100256503cdec95401ea25c6928f1737/samples-final/AspNetCore-EchoBot-AppInsights)

The relevant lines are this:

```
CounterState = conversationState.CreateProperty<CounterState>(MyAppInsightsBotAccessors.CounterName),
```

From [this file](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/e58e997a100256503cdec95401ea25c6928f1737/samples-final/AspNetCore-EchoBot-AppInsights/Startup.cs#L127) creates the property on the state.

and

```
// Get the conversation state from the turn context that holds a simple counter
var state = await _stateAccessors.CounterState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new CounterState());

// Bump the turn count. 
state.TurnCount++;
```

From [this file](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/e58e997a100256503cdec95401ea25c6928f1737/samples-final/AspNetCore-EchoBot-AppInsights/MyAppInsightsBot.cs#L40) Accesses and utilizes the state.